# Use a numeric value in a linq dynamic query string

Tags: c#, linq, decimal, dynamic-linq

I am trying to make a dynamic linq query that will check for values based on a string.

First of all, here's the query:

```
objQry = from o in m_Db.OBJECTS.Where(whereConditions)
                      select o;

if(!objQry.Any())
{
    return null;
}
```

The `whereConditions` variable is a string I build and pass as parameter to find out the values I need. Here's examples of valid string:

`OBJ_NAME == \"Sword\" and OBJ_OWNER == \"Stan\"`
This will return any item whose name is "Sword" and owner is "Stan;

`OBJ_COLOR == \"Blue\" OR OBJ_COLOR == \"Red\"`
This will return any item which color is either blue or red.

Up to there, I'm fine, but now I have a problem: I need to check a decimal field. So I've tried this string:

`OBJ_NUMBER == 1`

But the query returns null even if there are objects which OBJ_NUMBER value is 1. It's a decimal. How can I indicate the query that they need to check for a decimal value?

**** EDIT ****

I have tried to "modify" the value passed so that it looks like this:

```
"CARD_NUMBER == Convert.ToDecimal(1)"
```

And now I have a different kind of error telling me this:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Any clues anyone? I'm still looking for a way to do this. Thanks!

**EDIT 2**

You can get an example of how my code is shaped by looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836453/dynamic-call-to-ef-database-to-retrieve-exact-wanted-data-instead-of-sorting-a-b).

Let's come back at this problem. I want to check decimal values. Let's say that OBJ_NUMBER is a decimal field.

Using `Dynamic Linq`, I tried to read the decimal field. Say that I want to get each object which number is 1.27. The `whereConditions` field would then be shaped like this:

```
OBJ_NUMBER == 1.27
```

But then I would get an `Invalid real literal '1.27'` error. I don't know why.

So I have tried Gert Arnold's solution and done this instead:

```
decimal bDecimal = decimal.Parce(valueToParse);

param = new ObjectParameter("cardNumber", typeof(decimal)) { Value = bDecimal };

valuesToUse.Add("CARD_NUMBER == @cardNumber");

listParams.Add(param);
```

But I ended up having 2 problems:

1. The first problem is that my `whereConditions` string is shaped this way:

   `CARD_NUMBER == @cardNumber`

   But I get the following error:

   `No property or field 'cardNumber' exists in type 'CARD'`

   Leading me to believe that it cannot make the link between the object parameter and the string used to do the query.
2. As you can see, I have a list of Params. This is because I cannot know for sure how many parameters the user will chose. So each time the user enters a new search field, I have to create a new ObjectParameter and store it in a list. Here's how I try to do the thing after:

   `ObjectParameter[] arrayParameters = listParams.ToArray();
   // Convert the list to an array`

And then, when I try to make the query:

```
cardQry = from c in mDb.CARD.Where(whereConditions, arrayParameters)
                               select c;
```

But to no avail.

**RESULTS**

Based on the answered question below, I have developped something "awful", yet functional.

First of all, I *ignore* every decimal fields because I could never reach them with dynamic linq. Instead, I do this:

```
var valuesToParse = keyValuePair.Value.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Here I parse the value and, if that's the case, the symbol.

decimal baseValue = decimal.Parse(valuesToParse[0]); 

if (valuesToParse.Count() > 1)
{
    string baseMethod = valuesToParse[1];

    if (baseMethod == ">" || baseMethod == ">=")
    {
        if (baseMethod == ">=")
        {
            baseValue--;
        }

        // The list is actually like this: Dictionary<string, object> list = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        list.Add("low", baseValue);

        // I kind of activate a tag telling me that the user is looking for a higher value.
        cardHigher = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (baseMethod == "<=")
        {
            baseValue++;
        }


        list.Add("low", baseValue);

        cardLower = true;
    }
}
else
{
    //lowParam = new ObjectParameter("dec", typeof(decimal)) { Value = baseValue };

    list.Add("low", baseValue);
}

cardNumberActivated = true;
```

At the end, when I get the list of objects, I do this:

```
if (list.Count > 0)
{

    (example)
    if (cardNumberActivated)
    {
        if (cardHigher)
        {
            q = mDb.CARD.Where("CARD_NUMBER >= @0", list["low"]).ToList();
        }
        else if (cardLower)
        {
            q = mDb.CARD.Where("CARD_NUMBER <= @0", list["low"]).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            q = mDb.CARD.Where("CARD_NUMBER == @0", list["low"]).ToList();
        }
    }
}

// Here we get the orinalData with the basic filters.
listToReturn.AddRange(cardQry);

if (q != null)
{
    //listToReturn.AddRange(q);
    for (int i = 0; i < listToReturn.Count; i++)
    {
        var priceList1 = listToReturn[i];
        if (!q.Any(_item => _item.CARD_NUMBER == priceList1.CARD_NUMBER))
        {
            listToReturn.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

And it works. This is **not** an elegant way to make it work, but I can validate the fields the way I wanted, and for this, I am thankful at last.

Comment: Now, I haven't tried, I will do so and tell you the result.

Comment: Nope, this provokes a "syntax" error.

Comment: Same result. Seems like there's something amiss. Maybe putting the value in quotes?

Comment: I have tried putting the value in double quotes, but now I end up having a "operator incompatible with operand types decimal and string" error... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not build a query string with inline predicate values. Use parameters in stead. Then will also be able to specify the type:

```
var whereConditions= "it.CARD_NUMBER = @cardNumber";
var param = new ObjectParameter("cardNumber", typeof(decimal)) { Value = 1 };
objQry = from o in m_Db.OBJECTS.Where(whereConditions, param);
```

**Edit**

I don't know what doesn't work in your code. Here's just a random piece of working code derived from one of my own projects:

```
var param1 = new ObjectParameter("dec", typeof(decimal)) { Value = 90000m };
var param2 = new ObjectParameter("int", typeof(int)) { Value = 90000 };
var q = ValueHolders.Where("it.DecimalValue >= @dec OR it.IntegerValue > @int",
                    param1, param2).ToList();
```

Note that `param1, param2` could also be an array of `ObjectParameter`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have a question for you. What if I actually wanted to get all card which card number was higher than 1? Would it be possible to do that?

Comment: The reason of the late response is that I dropped the issue at this time, but it came back to haunt me right now, so I have to work on it. ^^

Comment: And what if I have to stack many values? What if I add to look for any sword which card number is higher than one?

Comment: @HerveS You can use other operators like `>` and more predicates with `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Now my problem lies with stacking many ObjectParameters, how might I do that?

Comment: Oh! Si if the `param` value is actually a `List<ObjectParameter>`, it might work too?

Comment: Convert it to an array.

Comment: Well it does not work. I get the error `No property or field 'cardNumber' exists in type 'CARD'`. Seems like it is not able to "make the link" with the Object Parameter somehow.

Comment: Will do in a few minutes, stay tuned! :)

Comment: I have tried to add up more explanations to the post. Feel free to point out if you need more info on anything.

Comment: Even if I write the whereConditions like this: `it.CARD_NUMBER == @cardNumber`, it does not work.

Comment: I don't know what I can do for you. Maybe a piece of working code (see my edit) will help.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it led me to try something with a positive result. See updated answer up there.